# TensorFlow Fails on Fifth Retrieval

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

A simple TensorFlow program is failing consistently on the fifth attempt to retrieve.

Here's the program -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import sys

import tensorflow as tf

from utils import parse_csv

tf.enable_eager_execution()

train_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("iris_training.csv")

# skip the first header row
train_dataset = train_dataset.skip(1)

# parse each row
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_csv)

# randomize
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)

# batch
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32)

# iterator
iter = iter(train_dataset)

# View few entries from the batch
print()
for i in range(0, int(sys.argv[1])):
  features, label = iter.next()
  print("=> features:", features[0])
  print("=>    label:", label[0])
  print()
```

Here's the program output for five attempts -

```
./tensor.py 5 2>&1 | tail -5
  File "./tensor.py", line 33, in <module>
    features, label = iter.next()
  File "/Users/nv/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 519, in next
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```

Any idea why I encounter StopIteration?

Naga Vijayapuram

Answer (score 0):

Resolved for 5th attempt by changing this line -

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32)
```

To this -

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(1)
```

However, it fails on the 121st attempt now.

Answer (score 0):

The fail on 121st attempt is logical, as the csv file has 120 rows. Reproduced the issue of halting at 5th retrieval with batch size of 32 on both macOS Sierra (10.12.6) and macOS High Sierra (10.13.4) and then the solution - ability to retrieve all the 120 rows with batch size of 1.